# Forcing serial execution of __rdtsc() in a benchmark

Tags: c, windows, driver

We are trying to include a benchmark in the device driver for our hardware. The benchmarking routine looks like

```
for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++){
    tscStart = __rdtsc();
    WRITE_REGISTER_ULONG(ourRegister, ourValue)
    tscEnd = __rdtsc();

    duration = tscEnd - tscStart;
    // Store duration for later evaluation
}
```

Now, we seem to have a problem with the CPU reordering the calls, so that in about 50% of all cases, `duration` is way too short (we have an oscilloscope attached, so we are sure here).

Additional facts (I don't know if these are relevant, this is our first time with such drivers):

- `__rdtscp` has the same behaviour (on the machines that support it)
- We've tried surrounding every line with both `_mm_mfence` and/or `__cpuid` to force serialization of the commands
- The equivalent benchmark using `dummy = READ_REGISTER_ULONG(ourRegister)` is working as intended.
- Our hardware is connected via PCIe

Is there a way to get the machine to really wait for the write to return before taking the second time?

Comment: Weird stuff, have you looked at the assembly output to be sure the compiler isn't doing the reordering? Both `__cpuid` and `__rdtscp` should guarantee that the CPU serializes.

Comment: I should do this, I guess. Thanks! Prepare for the next question on how to find the disassembly for this particular method in a kernel mode driver (where i can't simply break into it) =)

Comment: I this were the case, how could I prevent the compiler from doing so? (Using the visual studio compiler)

Comment: The processor just doesn't wait for the PCIe transfer to complete so what you see on the scope isn't going to match your code timing at all.  Some background is [available here](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/pci-express-tlp-pcie-primer-tutorial-guide-1)

Comment: The function to prevent the compiler from reordering would be `_ReadWriteBarrier`, but reading Hans Passant's comment, it looks like that probably won't work either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Hans Passant and Damon in the comments, the attempt to use `__cpuid` to serialize the `__rdtsc` calls should work, but since the processor does not wait for the PCIe transfer to complete, my timing data is off anyhow.